# jQuery and all .js files not working locally, only externally

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a strange problem. I'm coding a website and inlcuding jQuery and some plugins, that are stored in 'js' folder. When I try to open it through a browser jQuery, plugins and all my custom scripts aren't working. Maybe it's somehing with my code, but don't think so. Of course when I inlude jQuery externally (Google API's) it works, but got some plugins and scripts which aren't hosted elsewhere. Here's my 'head' tag.

```
    <title>TOMTRANS - International Transport</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="screen" />

    <!-- S3Slider CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/s3slider.css" media="screen" />

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery Effects -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>

    <!-- S3Slider -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/s3Slider.js"></script>

    <!-- S3Slider Init -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#s3slider').s3Slider({
                timeOut : 3000,
                });
            });
    </script>

    <!-- HTML5 Shiv -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: what is the file path locally? do you have jquey locally

Comment: Look at the traffic with fiddler, you'll be able to see if your getting a 404 or 403 or something.

Comment: Open firebug on firefox or developer tools on chrome, it should show which js or css files are not found. If it's not found, it's either they do not exist, and if they do exist, check the file permissions.

Comment: Are you using a web server locally or loading it straight from the file system?

Answer (score 1):

By *locally* do you mean a local web server (i.e. http://localhost:12345/) or the file system (i.e. file:///C:/Users/John/Desktop/hello.htm)? If it's the latter, then it's probably the security settings. Some browsers block scripts from the file system by default.

Comment: I wasn't precise. I meant hosting server which I bought. Here you could see the problem: [link](http://man-of-the-north.pl/lab/tomtrans.eu/). And Firebug says (when pointed on jQuery in 'head' section): You don't have permission to access /lab/tomtrans.eu/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js. Same is with the plugin which I included.

Comment: I see now. It looks like a permission problem. At this point I looks..... hmmm nevermind, I just refreshed your page and the error is gone :-O Looked like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078527/jquery-not-loading/2078534#2078534) problem, but is seems you already figured it out :)

Comment: 'cause few moments ago I've uploaded .project file. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do

```
"./js/..."
```

I think it will work as with external jquery.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have solved my problem. It's my IDE fault - Aptana Studio 3. This bug occured because I didn't upload hidden .project file, while I copied it through default file browser (Ubuntu's Nautilus). When I used built-in AS3 ftp manager it also copied .project file, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but I have't found the answer to this very annoying problem so I am adding my solution.

If your physical folder path includes an underscore, it will fail.
So, if you dropped your website to lets say `C:\MyRoot\MyFolder_2\WebSite1\`  then it won't work. however, if you remove the underscore and it becomes `C:\MyRoot\MyFolder2\WebSite1\` it will suddenly work and jQuery will suddenly be loaded.