# jquery mobile css does not load from local, only from web

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

Someone must have the answer to this, it's driving me nuts!!!

I am testing a jquery mobile page and have the following in my index.html page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

It doesn't work. The page doesn't recognize the css or js. But when I load it over the network it works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

I've copied and downloaded those files over and over to check that I have the right local files. Why would it load from an external URL but not my local files?

Comment: Do you have a subfolder 'js' and subfolder 'css' relative to the folder where index.html is?

Comment: Can you point to the live files for us?

Comment: it is probably because you are not referring the correct url try starting with '/' which means start from the domain and give your path according to your domain.

Comment: this question is a dup of 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199975/jquery-and-all-js-files-not-working-locally-only-externally

Comment: Yes, I have js and css subfolders relative to the index.html folder. The live files are in the place where the links are above. I know hte index.html is working it just doesn't find the css.

Comment: Have you checked your security settings.  Have you looked at the error in something like firebug?

Comment: I'll check out both of these. Must be something very simple...

Comment: To everyone who comes to this question, the answer is in the comment on the answer left by darren. If you can't find it, here it is: When installing these css files locally, there are image files that need to be installed with them. And they need to be in a subfolder in the CSS folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a js folder and a css folder in the root of your project add a leading "/".  The leading slash will start you at the beginning of the domain.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: still no luck. Adding the leading "/" didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: I finally found the answer in another post. When installing these css files locally, there are image files that need to be installed with them. And they need to be in a subfolder in the CSS folder